# Exclude non minified java script from release build

Tags: ajax, visual-studio-2008, release, minify

I have a .NET library which provides some AJAX controls. The library is build with Visual Studio 2008. The ajax minifier task is used to auto generate minified javascript files.
In a debug build I need the original javascript files for debugging the javascript, but in a release build these have no usage.

What would you recommend? Ignore them in the release and let them blow up the file size? Would there be a penality in loading time? Or would you remove them from the release build? How? I could modify the project file and add a condition attribute. But this does not well integrate in Visual Studio.

EDIT:

To clearify: The primary question is: What are the arguments for including and excluding the non minified files.

UPDATE:

Just found a solution a nice solution for the auto exclusion. Hers a part of my project file:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <EmbeddedJavascript Include="MyJavascript.debug.js" />
  <EmbeddedResource Include="MyJavascript.js" />
</ItemGroup>
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\MicrosoftAjax\ajaxmin.tasks" />
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
  <ItemGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)' != 'Release' ">
    <EmbeddedResource Include="@(EmbeddedJavascript)" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <AjaxMin JsSourceFiles="@(EmbeddedJavascript)" JsSourceExtensionPattern="\.debug\.js$" JsTargetExtension=".js" />
</Target>
```

Comment: Why does adding a condition attribute so it's done only in Release mode not integrate well into visual studio?

Comment: Because you don't have an optical feedback. In order to know if a file is "release only", one would have to unload the project and view the source file.